# NodeJS/Express: parsing a csv file won't return the correct array

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

In NodeJS/express i'm parsing a csv file (with a size of 2MB). The parsing works fine, but when the function is called the return value stays empty.

I know it has something to do with the async functioning of the parsing probably, but I can't get it to work properly.

returning the results array doesn't work in the .on('end', ()) call of the parser.

```
const csv = require('csv-parser')

function readLines(file){
  let results = [];
  fs.createReadStream(file)
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', (data) => {
    if(Object.keys(data).length == 59){
      data['2'] = data['2'] + data['3']
      delete data['3']
    }
    results.push(data)
  })
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log(results) // this returns the parsed csv file correctly.

  });
  return results //this returns the empty array
}

app.post('/parse', (req, res) => {
  location = './uploads/' + req.body.file
  pf = readLines(location) //this is empty
  
  //console.log(pf)
  res.send('placeholder') //this is just to complete the request
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such cases, you can use a callback function:

```
const csv = require('csv-parser')

function readLines(file, cb) {
  let results = [];
  fs.createReadStream(file)
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', (data) => {
    if(Object.keys(data).length == 59){
      data['2'] = data['2'] + data['3']
      delete data['3']
    }
    results.push(data)
  })
  .on('end', () => {
    cb(results); // call the callback with `results` as an argument
  });
}

app.post('/parse', (req, res) => {
  location = './uploads/' + req.body.file
  readLines(location, (results) => {
    console.log(results);
    res.send(results);
  });
});
```

Returning in the `on('end')` event callback does not work because the `return` keyword refers to the *callback itself* and not the `readLines` function.